# How do I complement daily data according to data updated quarterly?

Tags: python, pandas

For different users, their datas are updated quarterly but not in the same day.

For user 'a', the pd.Series of his data are:

```
2018-01-01 556
2018-04-01 498
2018-07-02 318
```

The dates are indexes of the Series.
Similarly, for user 'b', his data is:

```
2018-01-02 123
2018-04-02 456
2018-07-01 789
```

First, I want to convert quarterly data to daily data. For example, for 'a', the data between '2018-01-02' and '2018-03-31' should still be 556 since it was not updated yet.

Then, I want to concat the data of 'a' and 'b' in a dataframe.The expected output should be:

```
             a    b
2018-01-01 556  NaN
2018-01-02 556  123
...
2018-03-31 556  123
2018-04-01 498  123
2018-04-02 498  456
2018-04-03 498  456
...
2018-06-30 498  456
2018-07-01 498  789
2018-07-02 318  789
```

Two questions puzzles me:

1. How to complement the missing date?
2. 'a' and 'b' were updated not in the same day. How to align them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) with forward filling misisng values by `ffill`:

```
df = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1, keys=('a','b')).asfreq('D').ffill()
print (df)
                a      b
2018-01-01  556.0    NaN
2018-01-02  556.0  123.0
2018-01-03  556.0  123.0
2018-01-04  556.0  123.0
2018-01-05  556.0  123.0
          ...    ...
2018-06-28  498.0  456.0
2018-06-29  498.0  456.0
2018-06-30  498.0  456.0
2018-07-01  498.0  789.0
2018-07-02  318.0  789.0

[183 rows x 2 columns]
```